# Fetch details of specific data item in recyclerview from mysql using php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I have a recyclerview with card layout. Populated view from MySQL database using PHP. Now, what I have to do is upon clicking any particular card it should open new activity showing image, name, price and description of that selected item. I have a second PHP file for fetching data item but cannot figure out a way to send data to PHP which would take data from android app and return information of only desired item in JSON.

I am using custom OnClickListener to open new activity. Can successfully pass itemname of selected data item to new activity. Need a way to pass that name to PHP so that it would return information from database for that particular itemname.

I'm using Volley library.

**ExampleItem.java**

```java
public class ExampleItem {

    private String mImgUrl;
    private String mItemname,mItemprice;

    public ExampleItem(String imgUrl, String itemname, String itemprice){

        mImgUrl = imgUrl;
        mItemname = itemname;
        mItemprice = itemprice;

    }

    public String getmImgUrl(){

        return mImgUrl;

    }

    public String getmItemname(){

        return mItemname;

    }

    public String getmItemprice(){

        return mItemprice;

    }

}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```java
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){

        mListener = listener;

    }

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList){

        mContext = context;
        mExampleList = exampleList;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.cardview_layout
                , viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder myViewHolder, int i) {

        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(i);

        String imageUrl = currentItem.getmImgUrl();
        String itemName = currentItem.getmItemname();
        String itemPrice = currentItem.getmItemprice();

        Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).fit().into(myViewHolder.mImageView);
        myViewHolder.mItemName.setText(itemName);
        myViewHolder.mItemPrice.setText(itemPrice);


        Log.d("URL is", imageUrl);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mItemName;
        public TextView mItemPrice;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            mItemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemName);
            mItemPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null){

                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){

                            mListener.onItemClick(position);

                        }

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

**ViewAllProds.java**

```java
public class ViewAllProds extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    Toolbar mToolbar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
    private MyAdapter mMyAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recyler_view_layout);

        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.viewallprod_toolbar);
        mToolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(ViewAllProds.this, 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();

        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        parseJSON();

    }

    private void parseJSON(){

        String url = "http://192.168.43.241/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url
                , "", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Log.d("Json String: ", response.toString().replace("\\",""));

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("products");

                    for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject prod = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String imgUrl = prod.getString("image_url");
                        String prodname = prod.getString("name");
                        String prodprice = prod.getString("price");

                        mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(imgUrl, prodname, prodprice));

                    }

                    mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(ViewAllProds.this, mExampleList);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mMyAdapter);

                    mMyAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ViewAllProds.this);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ProductDetail.class);

        ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        detailIntent.putExtra("name", clickedItem.getmItemname());
        startActivityForResult(detailIntent, 100);

    }
}
```

**get_product_details.php**

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

require 'db_config.php';

// connecting to db
$connect = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die("Could not connect");

if (isset($_GET["name"])) {
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $command = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = $name";

// get a product from products table
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $command);

if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
            $product["name"] = $result["name"];
            $product["price"] = $result["price"];
            $product["description"] = $result["description"];
            $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];
            $product["image_url"] = $row["image_url"];
            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: Well, your passing the name, shouldn't you pass the product id?
Also you should use mysqli_real_escape_string to protect the get from hackers

Comment: Do you get an error or something?

Comment: @Richard Housham No, I'm not getting error. The thing is I cannot figure out a way to send the itemname to the php so it could fetch the detail from mysql.

Comment: This line
 String url = "http://192.168.43.241/android_connect/get_all_products.php";
Should be something like
 String url = "http://192.168.43.241/android_connect/get_all_products.php?name="+name; But I have to say my Java days are long behind me and I've not done any android dev work (looks like you need to right click the url)

Comment: I guess URL needs no change. PHP code given above in question must do the job. Its just that I can't figure out a way to do it using JAVA code.